# android update application without any alert

Tags: android, publish, updates

I am writing an android application and I want to publish it to google play. After I publish, if I update my application, I don't want to alert(about the update) the users that installed my application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App updates are handled by the platform and the only way for **user** to set it to autoupdate is to tick proper option in Google Play app. App itself cannot do that.

Comment: I want to stop an auto update or an alert about the update? Is this possible?

Comment: No, not really as you are not able to know what's the value of that setting for your app in users' Play application